# Push multiple objects to an already initialized, empty object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

People is my model, data is my new information, and the forEach is how I am trying to insert the new data into my model, but formatted to only the information I care about

```js
people = [{name: '', age: 0}];

data = [
  {id: '123', name: 'Bob', lastName: 'Guy', age: 40}, 
  {id: '321', name: 'Michael', lastName: 'Park', age: 20}, 
]

data.forEach(person => {
   people.push({
      name: person.name,
      age: person.age,
   });
});
```

However, the result I get is this:

```js
people = [
  {name: '', age: 0}, 
  {name: 'Bob', age: 40}, 
  {name: 'Michael', age: 20}
];
```

I'm trying to have the object array look like this instead:

```js
people = [
  {name: 'Bob', age: 40}, 
  {name: 'Michael', age: 20}
];
```

However, I would like to know if theres a way to do it without an extra line of code (like popping the first element), and if theres a way to do it in one command? If not, I am open to suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: The array you're pushing to has the object w/ the empty name/0 age--if you don't want it there why do you put it there? Are you asking how to have a default array if `data` is empty?

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought I needed to initialize the object before storing information in it. I tested it and it looks like I did not have to do that

Comment: if you need strict structure use typescript

Comment: @webdesignnoob You *do* need to create the array you're pushing into, but it can be empty. That said, you can do a `map`, e.g., `const people = data.map(({ name, age }) => ({ name, age }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the original array and not only that but also you're mutating the array.

You can use the function `Array.prototype.map` in order to generate a new array with the desired data.

```js
const people = [{name: '', age: 0}];

const data = [
  {id: '123', name: 'Bob', lastName: 'Guy', age: 40}, 
  {id: '321', name: 'Michael', lastName: 'Park', age: 20}, 
]

const result = data.map(person => ({
  name: person.name,
  age: person.age,
}));

console.log(result);
```

You can also keep the desired keys and by using the functions `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` you can build the expected result:

```js
const model = ["name", "age"];
const data = [
  {id: '123', name: 'Bob', lastName: 'Guy', age: 40}, 
  {id: '321', name: 'Michael', lastName: 'Park', age: 20}, 
]

const result = data.map(person => model.reduce((r, m) => ({...r, [m]: person[m]}), {}), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need to implement different person models, you can dinamically create the objects like this

```
peopleModel = [{ name: "", age: 0 }];

data = [
  { id: "123", name: "Bob", lastName: "Guy", age: 40 },
  { id: "321", name: "Michael", lastName: "Park", age: 20 },
];

const keysArr = Object.keys(peopleModel[0]);
const totalKeys = keysArr.length;

const people = data.reduce((acc, personObj) => {
  const obj = {};
  keysArr.forEach((key) => {
    if (personObj[key]) {
      obj[key] = personObj[key];
    }
  });
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(people);

/* logs [
  {name: 'Bob', age: 40}, 
  {name: 'Michael', age: 20}
];
*/
```

but if you need a different model like

```
peopleModel = [{ name: "", age: 0, lastName: "" }]
```

you will get for the log the following:

```
[
      {name: 'Bob', age: 40, lastName: 'Guy'}, 
      {name: 'Michael', age: 20, lastName: 'Park'}
    ];
```

that way you do not need to hardcode the keys